# SD card reader dead, in lenovo g4050

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sd-card, pci

I installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS and has been impossible to use the buit in SD card reader. I've found some related solutions here, but none work'd.
Some few have solved this issue by downloading the realtek driver. 
But, I'm not shure the SD card reader is a realtek one.

also installed the libccid package but no use..

This is the outcome of lspci:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)
    00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
    00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
    00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 0e)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
    02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

And the result of lspci -v:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 107
Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 3050 [size=8]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
Kernel driver in use: i915

00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 103
I/O ports at 3048 [size=8]
I/O ports at 305c [size=4]
I/O ports at 3040 [size=8]
I/O ports at 3058 [size=4]
I/O ports at 3020 [size=32]
Memory at 90804000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 105
Memory at 90700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Memory at 90600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Kernel driver in use: mei_txe

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 106
Memory at 90800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: fast devsel
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
Memory behind bridge: 90500000-905fffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
Memory behind bridge: 90400000-904fffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 0e) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at 90805000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 7
Memory at 90806000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=32]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
```

¿is the `PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port` the SD Card Reader? it appears that is using a driver, but it's not working...

coult it be because i've change this in the grub?:
http://www.ubuntu-guia.com/2010/08/ubuntu-no-lee-tarjeta-memoria.html

Seems there's a common suffering with the SD cards, so I hope solving my case can be useful for the community.

Cheers!

Comment: hey there! were you ever able to resolve this one?